# Error al instalar app "Google Play Protect" Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter

Estoy desarrollando una app con Flutter y venia utilizando appdistribution de Firebase para enviarla a dispositivos y probarla sin inconvenientes. En un momento tuve un problema con el logueo con google pero pude solucionarlo y luego de esto al querer volver a publicar la app desde firebase me apareció el siguiente cartel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi archivo android/app/buildgradle es el siguiente:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.app.recipies_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
}
```

como dato adicional yo tengo una carpeta de produccion en donde esta el problema y una carpeta de una version antigua de la app y eso no me dio ese problema.Como alternativa pense en pasar los archivos .dart de la carpeta lib de la app de produccion a la antigua y cargar algunos plugins pero eso hizo que me de error nuevamente. Al volver la carpeta antigua para atrás dejando todo como estaba anteriormente vuelve a darme el error a pesar de haber ejecutado un "Flutter clean". Alguna idea? En caso de necesitar mas información no duden en pedirla. Busqué informacion en StackOverflow pero ninguna opción solucionó el problema y tampoco encuentro la causa.

Comment: Esto no es un error, esto es una advertencia, del lado de flutter no hay nada que puedas hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 3 opciones para solucionar este problema:

- Deshabilitar Play Protect en Play Store -> Play Protect -> Icono de configuración -> Escanear dispositivo en busca de amenazas de seguridad
- Publicar aplicación en Google Play Store
- Enviar una apelación a [Play Protect](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Diego. Sabés que hizo que aparezca esto? Analytics tal vez?